# JPA under concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, jpa, thread-safety

my application connect postgres DB using hibernate JPA, if i have only 1 thread to write data to DB, it takes forever to finish the writing, then i use 10 threads, it cause deadlock problem in DB. shouldn't the JPA handle the thread control automatically?

here is my hibernate configurations:

applicationContext.xml:

```
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="javax.persistence.Persistence"
    factory-method="createEntityManagerFactory" destroy-method="close" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg value="${persistence_unit}" />
    <constructor-arg>
      <util:map>
        <entry key="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="${db_url}" />
        <entry key="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="${db_user}" />
        <entry key="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="${db_password}" />      

        <!-- Connection provider properties.-->
        <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="${hibernate_c3p0_max_size}" />
        <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="${hibernate_c3p0_min_size}" />
        <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="${hibernate_c3p0_acquire_increment}" />
        <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="${hibernate_c3p0_idle_test_period}" />
        <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="${hibernate_c3p0_max_statements}" />
        <entry key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="${hibernate_c3p0_timeout}" />

      </util:map>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```

operational-config.properties:

```
hibernate_c3p0_max_size=100
hibernate_c3p0_min_size=1
hibernate_c3p0_acquire_increment=1
hibernate_c3p0_idle_test_period=60
hibernate_c3p0_max_statements=0
hibernate_c3p0_timeout=30
hibernate_max_fetch_depth=3
hibernate_generate_statistics=false
```

with multithreads writing, got the following error:

```
2013-Feb-12 14:04:26.621    ERROR   o.h.u.JDBCExceptionReporter o.h.u.JDBCExceptionReporter,101 Batch entry 0 insert into TAGS (name, tagtype, id) values ('2135daa6-6d88-43aa-9a7d-cc5ee5735893', '1', '10004') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
2013-Feb-12 14:04:26.621    WARN    o.h.u.JDBCExceptionReporter o.h.u.JDBCExceptionReporter,100 SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
2013-Feb-12 14:04:26.622    ERROR   o.h.u.JDBCExceptionReporter o.h.u.JDBCExceptionReporter,101 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tags_name_key"
2013-Feb-12 14:04:26.627    ERROR   o.h.e.d.AbstractFlushingEventListener   o.h.e.d.AbstractFlushingEventListener,324   Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

...
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into TAGS (name, tagtype, id) values ('2135daa6-6d88-43aa-9a7d-cc5ee5735893', '1', '10004') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.


WARNING: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@412ad7b3 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
Feb 12, 2013 2:05:13 PM com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector run
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@412ad7b3 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
    Managed Threads: 3
    Active Threads: 3
    Active Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@86fbfc2 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@60965de1 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@2fed9051 (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1)
    Pending Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@159dce6c
```

Comment: It's unlikely to be database-level deadlocking, as PostgreSQL detects deadlocks and aborts all but one of the deadlocked transactions. More likely a Hibernate/JPA level issue. What Hibernate version? What app server/environment?

Comment: JPA 2.0, Hibernate 3.5.5, running on Linux 2.6.18-308.8.2.el5 x86_64. now i m wondering if i need to add lock in the JPA level for reading/writing specifically?

Comment: Consider updating to the current Hibernate first, it could easily be a bug. The latest 3.x is 3.6.9.Final .

Comment: It might also help to get the underlying exception that caused the batch to fail.